# Axios API request doesn't send full referer in Vue.js

Tags: php, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have a Vue app under `http://localhost:8080` and PHP API under `http://vue-api.test`. API requests are handled in Axios.

The problem is that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in my API gives me always `http://localhost:8080/` even if the request is sent from `http://localhost:8080/page` or `http://localhost:8080/bla-bla-bla`. Simply full path is cutted.

I tried to set different policies in Axios via headers  `headers: {'Referrer-Policy': 'unsafe-url'}`, but it always gives me only hostname, not the full path (`http://localhost:8080/page` or `http://localhost:8080/bla-bla-bla`).

I need to know the full path of the page in my API where the request has been invoked from.

Headers in my API:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Referrer-Policy');
```

Comment: _“I need to know the full path of the page in my API where the request has been invoked from.”_ - then send it as an additional parameter. Unless you were in an environment your are in full control of (regarding browser configuration, extensions, firewalls, …), relying on the referrer is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The browser has full control over the Referer header for security reasons, you can't change it with javascript client side.
But, if you set:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="unsafe-url">
```

When rendering the page server-side, the browser understands this allowance is coming from the server so it will use that to set the `Referrer-Policy` header accordingly.